# Why isn't special character "ù" being replaced in my substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

When I tried using the simple substitution below in a regex tester, it works fine. But when I use it in Perl code, the `ù` are not being replaced:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my $file = 'test.html';
my $str = read_file($file);

$str =~ s/ù/u/g; 

write_file("out/$file", $str);
```

Here is a sample text I wanted to change:

```
ùmbrella ùnder ùùùùù ùtters
```

to

```
umbrella under uuuuu utters
```

Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: @siam thanks! I had to add "use utf8;" on top as well

Comment: @siam: You're thinking of Python! That's just a comment in Perl.

Comment: [File::Slurp is broken and wrong.](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2015/08/fileslurp-is-broken-and-wrong.html)

Comment: `my $file = test.html;` is a syntax error; I fixed it in your question because you didn't mention any syntax errors and I assume it's just a copy-paste error.

Comment: The program already does what you ask it to do. (It does it badly, though, so do read my answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works as-is if your script and the input file are encoded with the same encoding.

```
$ cat>test.html
ùmbrella ùnder ùùùùù ùtters

$ perl a.pl

$ cat out/test.html
umbrella under uuuuu utters
```

---

Your program is buggy, though. Let's say we're talking about UTF-8. Perl actually sees

```
$str =~ s/\xC3\xB9/u/g;
```

While this isn't so bad, imagine if you had

```
$str =~ s/[ùú]/u/g;
```

Perl would see that as

```
$str =~ s/[\xC3\xB9\xC3\xBA]/u/g;
```

This would turn `ù` (`C3 B9`) into `uu` and `é` (`C3 A9`) into `u<garbage>`.

For Perl to recognize any non-ASCII character in your program, you must ensures the program file is encoded using UTF-8, and you need to add `use utf8;` at the top of the file. With `use utf8;`, Perl sees

```
$str =~ s/[ùú]/u/g;
```

or rather

```
$str =~ s/[\xF9\xFA]/u/g;  # F9 and FA are the Unicode Code Points for ù and ú
```

---

However, adding `use utf8;` is only half of the solution. We changed how Perl sees the regular expression, but we didn't change `$str`, so they can't possibly match anymore. We are comparing the encoding of `ù` (`C3 B9`) with the Unicode Code Point of `ù` (`F9`)

**Always decode your inputs. Always encode your outputs.**

We've already decoded one input (the program itself). Now we need to do the same to the contents of the file.

Similarly, we need to encode outputs. This includes not just the contents of the file, but warnings output to STDERR.

Much of that is done by

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

It adds an encoding layer to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, and sets the default encoding layer for files opened within the lexical scope of the pragma.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_qfn = 'test.html';
my $out_qfn = 'out/test.html';

# :encoding(UTF-8) is added by "use open".
open(my $in_fh,  '<', $in_qfn)   or die("Can't open \"$in_qfn\": $!\n");
open(my $out_fh, '>', $out_qfn)  or die("Can't create \"$out_qfn\": $!\n");

while (<$in_fh>) {
   s/[ùú]/u/g;
   print($out_fh $_);
}
```

If you use File::Slurp, you'll need to tell it to decode the file (or decode it yourself) because its `open` is not in scope of the `use open`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp qw( read_file write_file );

my $in_qfn = 'test.html';
my $out_qfn = 'out/test.html';

my $file = read_file($in_qfn, binmode => ':encoding(UTF-8)');

$file =~ s/[ùú]/u/g; 

write_file($out_qfn, { binmode => ':encoding(UTF-8)' }, $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use utf8; # <-- Added this
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
my $file = test.html; my $str;

$str = read_file($file);
$str =~ s/ù/u/g; 

write_file("out/$file",$str);
```

Comment: The `use utf8` pragma tells Perl that your _source code file_ is saved with utf8 encoding.

Comment: In other words, you still need to tell Perl to encode the output as UTF-8.

Comment: The modified program leaves the input file unchanged. While adding `use utf8;` is proper, it's only part of the solution. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are a couple of issues here. Firstly, you're using File::Slurp and you aren't telling it that the data is UTF-encoded. That means your two-byte "ù" characters will be interpreted as two single-byte characters. Secondly, you have a literal "ù" in your code, but you don't tell Perl to interpret your source code as UTF8, so you'll probably have the single-byte ISO-8859 representation.

The two single-byte characters in your input string won't match the single-byte character in your source code, so the replacement won't work.

You need to a) tell Perl that your source code is UTF8 and b) handle the decoding of input and encoding of output correctly. I recommend throwing out File::Slurp and doing it yourself.

I also recommend not slurping files, but processing them a line at a time whenever possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $file = 'test.html';
open my $in_fh, '<:utf8', $file or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>:utf8', "out/$file" or die $!;

while (<$in_fh>) {
    s/ù/u/g;

    print $out_fh $_;
}
```

**Update:** Here's a really simple subroutine that I use to get information about strings.

```
sub string_chars {
  say join ':', map { ord } split //, $_[0];
}
```

If you add this to your code and pass it 'ù' - you get the output "249" (which is the codepoint for 'ù' in ISO-8859-1). If you pass it your `$str` value, you get:

```
'195:185:109:98:114:101:108:108:97:32:195:185:110:100:101:114:32:195:185:195:185:195:185:195:185:195:185:32:195:185:116:116:101:114:115:10'
```

The repeated '195:185' is the two-byte representation of 'ù' in UTF8.

Comment: Here's a simpler one: `sub string_chars { say sprintf "%vX", $_[0] }` (Bonus, the numbers are in hex!)